# how to get datagrampacket in php

Tags: java, php, udp, datagram

I have a `Socket` in Java and send a `DatagramPacket` that I need to read from a PHP page that then writes it to a file, but I cannot find a way to do it.

This is the Socket code in Java:

```
private void openSocket(){
    try {
          client = new DatagramSocket();
          System.out.println(" Socket client açıldı.. ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" PosyByte : Open Socket Hata " + e.toString());
    }
}
private InetAddress getIpaddress(String adress){

    try {
              InetAddress ipaddress = InetAddress.getByName(adress);
              return ipaddress;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(" PosyByte : getIpaddress Hata!  " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
private DatagramPacket createDatagramPacket(byte[] buf , int length , InetAddress ipadress , int port){
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, length, ipadress, port);
return dp;
}

private void sendDataOnSocket (DatagramPacket udp){
    try {
        client.send(udp);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(" PosyByte : SendDataonSocket Hata!  " + ex.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println(" PosyByte : SendDataonSocket Hata!  " + e.toString());
    }
}
private void closeSocket(){   
client.close();
 System.out.println(" Socket client kapandı.. ");
}
```

Comment: This might help reading: http://www.phpgangsta.de/udp-nachrichten-versenden-und-empfangen (it is in german, but has good examples that speak for themselves) At the bottom of the article is what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SA-MP (San Andreas Multiplayer) API](http://forum.sa-mp.com/showthread.php?t=355574) I wrote in PHP, it sends and receives UDP (Datagram) packets. Taking a look at the source might help you.

I also [wrote one in Java](http://forum.sa-mp.com/showthread.php?t=354062), so you can compare the differences.